# GPS neo-6m do I need to request data?

Tags: gps, psoc

I've worked with this GPS on Arduino and it was pretty easy. But currently, I am trying to connect it to PSOC. And I'm interested if someone knows, do I need to ask GPS for data or it will try to find satellites and send data without any writing on a port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it automatically tries to find satellites after it is powered.
I initialized my Tx and Rx UART pins and then just read data from Rx. Led on GPS starts blinking after it finds satellite, even when Rx and Tx pins are switched, because of this I assume that it doesn't need any requests. + I have looked on code from TinyGPS library, haven't seen any requests for data. Plz, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while trying to solve configuring neo 6m GSP. The reply is probably late but it might benefit others, so yes, you can poll your location when you need it. there are propriety messages that can allow you do that. It also allows you to stop the automatic sending of messages. Attached below is a link to the datasheet that explains how to do that and a link to a CRC calculator that calculates neo 6m frame.

https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox6_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28GPS.G6-SW-10018%29_Public.pdf

[Neo 6M CRC calculator]
http://www.hhhh.org/wiml/proj/nmeaxor.html